# I've got a problem with c++ about <stdio.h> library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, stdio

I'm learning C++ for my school. I' m using Visual studio to code C++, I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("cd.inp", "r", stdin);
    freopen("cd.out", "w", stdout);
    int a, b;
    while (true){
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << a << ' ' << b;
        break;
    }
    fclose(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);
}
```

I've got these errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C4996   'freopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using freopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. clock_degrees   F:\CODING\C++\clock_degrees\clock_degrees\clock_degrees.cpp 11

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning C6031   Return value ignored: 'freopen'.    clock_degrees   F:\CODING\C++\clock_degrees\clock_degrees\clock_degrees.cpp 11

What should I do now?
I've got some problems about **scanf** and **printf** instead of **freopen** too. I thought the problems'd come from <stdio.h> library.

Comment: What you should do now, is actually use C++ instead of C. `freopen` is a C library function, and it is not always specified how C library's standard input/output functions have any bearing on `std::cin` and `std::cout`. Even if you address this compiler diagnostic, this may or may not work. You should look up how to use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`, in order to open streams that read or write from files, and use that instead of `std::cin` and `std::cout`, with the underlying file streams hijacked via `freopen`. P.S. `scanf` and `printf` are also C.

Comment: You need to get examples of C++ coding from somewhere else. This is a mishmash of C and C++. It's hard enough to learn C++.

Comment: Unrelated note: In C++ you should use `#include <cstdio>` rather than using the deprecated "stdio.h" if you insist on using the C functions.

Comment: cool that someone deleted my comment which by now was the only comment actually helping instead of people telling tales about how c and c++ headers don't mix...

Comment: Recommend you add error detection / handling at the formatted extraction.  Also, 'cin' is a stream (i.e. of c++)  ... freopen deals with files (c-style).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ifstream` and `ofstream` instead:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

// don't do using namespace std;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::ios_base;

int main() {
  ifstream in;
  ofstream out;
  in.exceptions(ios_base::failbit | ios_base::badbit);
  out.exceptions(ios_base::failbit | ios_base::badbit);
  try {
    in.open("cd.inp");
    int a, b;
    // The while loop is pointless
    in >> a >> b;
    out.open("cd.out");
    out << a << ' ' << b;
  } catch (ios_base::failure const& e) {
    // Error handling 
    return -1;
  } 
}
```

- [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10147399)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the top. If you use `freopen`, the compiler will think it is not safe. So, I suggest that you could use   [freopen_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/freopen-s-wfreopen-s?view=vs-2019).